# How do you reference the MultiSelect widget in kendo

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I get the following exception when I reference the kendo multiselect widget.

'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory' does not contain a definition for 'MultiSelect' and no extension method 'MultiSelect' accepting a first argument of type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I add a reference to this widget?

Comment: Can you please post sample code so we can better troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Multiselect](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/multiselect/index.html) demo? Do other widgets work? Have you followed the steps in the [Getting Started](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction) section and verified your install is ok?

The following code works in an MVC4 view utilizing Razor view engine (it's lifted from the demo, but without the extraneous pretty stuff and tags):

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
      .Name("required")
      .Placeholder("Select attendees...")
      .BindTo(new List<string>() {
          "Steven White",
          "Nancy King",
          "Anne King",
          "Nancy Davolio",
          "Robert Davolio",
          "Michael Leverling",
          "Andrew Callahan",
          "Michael Suyama",
          "Anne King",
          "Laura Peacock",
          "Robert Fuller",
          "Janet White",
          "Nancy Leverling",
          "Robert Buchanan",
          "Andrew Fuller",
          "Anne Davolio",
          "Andrew Suyama",
          "Nige Buchanan",
          "Laura Fuller"
      })
      .Value(new string[] { "Anne King", "Andrew Fuller" })
)
```